# How can I ignore any string that the user inputs?

Tags: c++, cin, cout

The user should input a double but how would I get the program to ignore a string or a char if they put one in. The problem with my current code is when I put in a string the program will spam and fill the screen with the cout << "What is the length of the rectangle";

```
double length;

do {
    cout << "What is the length of the rectangle: ";
    cin >> length;
    bString = cin.fail();
} while (bString == true);
```

Comment: What about `while (bString == false);` Btw, you didn't say what's wrong with your code.

Comment: @DimChtz when I use (bstring == false); has the same effect as true

Comment: `std::cin::fail()` returns `true` if last call to `cin` failed. So, since you want to loop for as long as `cin` doesn't fail, you need to `while (bString == false);`.

Comment: yes I realise this however the same thing happens when I type in a string. It simply spams the output

Comment: You 're doing something wrong http://cpp.sh/9znuz

Comment: If you want to ignore it, why not just ask again if the user inputs a string thus ignoring the string?

Comment: Please don't edit something like *"Solved"* into your question. Instead, accept the answer you find most useful by clicking the check-mark next to it. This will properly mark the question as solved on a system level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do {
    cout << "What is the length of the rectangle: ";
    cin >> length;
    bString = cin.fail();
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
} while (bString == true);
```

This is the code I found that works for my issue.

Answer (score 0):

`cin.fail()` will not differentiate between integers and floating point numbers.

The best way to check is by using `std::fmod()` function to check if the reminder is more than zero. if it is then its a floating point number.

Here is the code

```
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    double length;
    std::cout <<"What is the length of the rectangle: ";
    std::cin >> length;

    if (std::cin.fail())
    {
        std::cout<<"Wrong Input..."<<std::endl;
    } else 
    {
        double reminder = fmod(length, 1.0);
        if(reminder > 0)
           std::cout<<"Yes its a number with decimals"<<std::endl;
        else
            std::cout<<"Its NOT a decimal number"<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Beware that this code will not differentiate between 12 and 12.0.

Answer (score -1):

If the user inputs an invalid data type, cin will fail. You can check using this

```
double length;
while(true)
{
    std::cout << "What is the length of the rectangle: ";
    std::cin >> length;

    if (std::cin.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid data type...\n";
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore();
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use `NULL`. Why would you?